# ASP.NET Razor tag helper inside text string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

In my razor page view I'm populating a model to pass to a partial, like this:

**Razor Page**

```
@{
    if (Model.Success)
    {
        Model.AlertMessage = new AlertMessage()
        {
            Title = "Email Confirmed",
            Description = "Your email has been confirmed, you can now <a href=\"/login\">login</a> to your account."
        };
    }
    else
    {
        Model.AlertMessage = new AlertMessage()
        {
            Title = "Confirmation Failed",
            Description = "Your email could not be confirmed, please <a href=\"/confirmemail\">try again</a>."
        };
    }
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <partial name="_Partials/Alerts/_AlertMessage", model="Model.AlertMessage"/>
</div>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model AlertMessage

<div class="alert">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto align-self-center alert-icon">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <span class="alert-title">@Model.Title</span>
        <p class="alert-content">@Html.Raw(@Model.Description)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is working, but I'm wondering if it is possible to use a razor tag helper inside the text string? To somehow replace the hard coded anchor tag `<a href=\"/login\">login</a>` with a tag helper `<a asp-page="/Login">` and have it render the HTML properly?

Comment: I would extend the model with a new filed Link and pass it into Partial View.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (Model.Success)
{
    Model.AlertMessage = new AlertMessage()
    {
        Title = "Email Confirmed",
        Description = "Your email has been confirmed, you can now" + @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login") + "to your account."
    };
}
```

Comment: I think you can do the above, Check the overloads, the first param is your text then the next is the action, and you might need a controller.

Comment: Yes, this does indeed work but I was hoping to not have to create a controller for this case

Comment: Where does your Login Action live?

Comment: Not sure if you are using Entity, but if you are it would be @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account")

Comment: If you do have to make a contoller for a get it should be REALLY short:
Like, 
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonomous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
return View();
}
Wouldn't even need a Dispose Method bc there is no db handshake